# JavaScript does not run on first load if I include the jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am facing a very strange problem where my javascript code does not run the first time the page is loaded. If I reload/refresh the page, the script runs fine.

After some hit-and-trial's I realized that if I remove the **jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js** library from the previous page (which redirects to my current page) then the script is running as expected.

Can anyone please help on why this is occurring and how can I resolve it ?

Update:
On opening the hpme page (which contains the link to the page containing the JS), I can see the following error in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobile' of undefined .

Please note that this home page is basically a simple code with library declarations and html links.

Edit :
I had missed the jQuery lib earlier and hence the Uncaught TypeError.
Now, my libraries are in the following order :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Now there are no errors in my console, but still the JS in the next page does not run in the first load. Oddly, if I remove the **jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js** library, the JS works fine.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console of your browser?

Comment: Yes I can see Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobile' of undefined  error in my console. Have updated the same in my question.

Comment: Try to change the order of including the js files, include jquery js first and then jquery mobile's related js.

Comment: Have you included jQuery 1.8+ before jQuery Mobile?

Comment: If you get that error, 1) you're using jQuery version 1.7 or earlier 2) you're loading jQuery-Mobile before jQuery.

Comment: there could be a conflict between both jQuery-Mobile and jQuery-ui. if you remove jQuery-ui, the problem disappears.

Comment: You said the error message stated in the question is now gone. So, could you post the Javascript code that's "not working"?

Comment: @MelanciaUK Any javascript code is not running. I tried with a simple alert statement and that dosen't run either. <script type="text/javascript">
 
 $(function() {
 
  alert("hello");
 });
 </script>   Also, I must mention again that the JS only does not work in the first load. If I refresh the page then the JS code gets executed.

Comment: @Omar I removed the jQuery-ui in both the pages, yet the problem persists.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/s21dzs8t/

Comment: @MelanciaUK, I have two pages. Page A has a hyperlink which points to Page B which contains the JS. The problem arises when the jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js library is included in **Page A**.

Comment: Once again, please share your Javascript code and the markup. When using jQuery Mobile the markup matters. A lot.

Comment: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Single Page Model

jQuery Mobile loads external pages via Ajax; when you have a link to another page, jQM loads first page div `<div data-role="page">` in that page and neglects other tags outside that div.

If you have JS code that you want to run in the loaded page, you have to place it inside page div.

```
<div data-role="page">
   <!-- JS code -->
</div>
```

Comment: your solution works out perfectly. Thanks. However, in my JS code, I am adding new rows to the html table dynamically. So, the page just keeps on loading infinitely. Any tips on where should I place the JS in my div ?

Comment: Solved the above using $(document).on("pagecreate",function(event). Thanks still.

Comment: @user3933833 it depends on your code. If you post a separate question with relevant details, it'll be easier to find a solution.