# Javascript only working after first refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, refresh

Any ideas why the javascript function below only works after I refresh the page one time? 
I tried putting the function at the bottom of the page, but it still does not work.
I feel it has to do with the order which the code is being run, but I cannot identify specifically where.

```
    function incrementIssue(id) {
        var row = "#row" + id;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("issue"+id+"Upvote").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            //$(row.toString()).find('.ui-icon').removeClass('ui-icon-custom').addClass('ui-icon-arrow-d');

        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","incrementIssue.php?q="+id,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }

    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/themes/blue/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Pithy</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="issues.php">View Issues</a></li>
            <li><a href="add.php">Add Issue</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-split-theme="c"  >    

    <?php

    mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to
    connect to database! Please try again later.");
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    //Fetching from your database table.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if ($result) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $issue = $row["issueName"];
            $upvotes = $row["upvotes"];
            $id = $row["issueID"];
            echo "<li data-icon=\"arrow-u\" id=\"row".$id . "\"> <a data-transition=\"pop\" href=\"point.php?id=". intval($id). "\">".$issue ."</a><a href=\"javascript:incrementIssue(".$id.");\"></a> <span id=\"issue".$id."Upvote\" class=\"ui-li-count\">" .$upvotes."</span></li>";

        }
    }

    ?>
      </ul>

      </div>

      <div data-role="footer">
        <h6>See what's important.</h6>
      </div>
    </div> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You mean to say that no matter whichever link you click from your result set, the `incrementIssue()` function does not execute other than once?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with Ajax ( I don't know php but i had something similar in my asp.net mvc app). I resolve this problem using jquery and "on" method. 
Please look at this [Jquery api ON](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337374/javascript-does-not-run-on-first-load-if-i-include-the-jquery-mobile-1-4-3-min-j). This will probably work all of those who have a page with javascript in it. The problem is jquery needs to have a attribute in a div tag `<div data-role="page">` surrounding the javascript. Have a look at the link I posted in the edit.

Comment: the problem is, I don't want the function to run onload. It's an ajax function, so I only want it to be run when someone clicks a button

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337374/javascript-does-not-run-on-first-load-if-i-include-the-jquery-mobile-1-4-3-min-j)

Comment: No problemo =) All it takes is a little googling :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your funtion under  "settimeout" javascript function...and provide timeout as 100ms